# If a block matrix is full rank, can we necessarily find the entries of each of the blocks of the inverted matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a block matrix $\mathbf{M}$ that is **full rank**:

$$
\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then we know that

$$
\mathbf{M}^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1} & -(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1}\mathbf{BD}^{-1} \\ -\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1} & \quad \mathbf{D}^{-1}+\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1}\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
$$

by properties of matrix inversion.

My question now is if the $\mathbf{M}$ being full rank means that $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})$ is invertible (or has a determinant that is non-zero). Is there a relation here?

Comment: If $M: V \to V$ has full rank then the dimension of its image is that of $V$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, this means that $M$ is surjective and injectivity follows from this too. Then $M$ is an invertible since it's an isomorphism. Your formula for the inverse of a matrix is not correct since $D$ may be zero while $M$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\bf D$ is invertible as you mentioned and suppose that $\bf A-\bf B\bf D^{-1}\bf C$ is not invertible. Therefore there is $\bf u\neq 0$ such that:
$$
(\bf A-\bf B\bf D^{-1}\bf C)\bf u=0.
$$
Define $\bf v=-\bf D^{-1}\bf C \bf u$. Then we have:
$$
\bf A \bf u +\bf B\bf v=0.
$$
On the other hand we have:
$$
\bf Cu+Dv= D(D^{-1}Cu+v)=D(-v+v)=0.
$$
Therefore the vector $[\bf u, v]^T$ is in the null space of $\bf M$ and therefore it is not full rank.

This shows that if $\bf D$ is invertible, then $\bf M$ is full rank iff  $\bf A-\bf B\bf D^{-1}\bf C$ is invertible.